# How to bind lost focus to a command in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PrimaryCountyFIPS" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Margin="3"
                        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                        IsEditable="True"
                        LostFocus="{Binding LostFocusCommand }"
                        ItemContainerStyle ="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IncludePrimZipCodeCheckBox}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:GeocoderDataCleanerViewModel}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DestinationColsDictionary}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:GeocoderDataCleanerViewModel}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=PrimaryCountyFIPSField, Mode=OneWay}">
        </ComboBox>
```

> I have a ComboBox that I am wanting to Bind it's lost focus event to a command that I have in it's ViewModel. When I try to bind it I get an error that says "LostFocus is not a method" How would I go about binding it to that Command or is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
    <ComboBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: What is the <i:> referencing? EDIT: It's referencing "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" for anyone that might need it. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Sorry i  forogt to mention it in the first place
But  please note:
generally when you do need to use it you are very likely to have a logical error at least in my experience

Comment: what you probably want to do is bind the combobox to an observableCollection and use the propertyChaanged event of it

Comment: @DenisSchaf sometimes you want to trigger propertychanged on keypress (for live validation UI) and also bind to focus lost as well e.g. for cascading data changes that you want the user to complete data entry before triggering.

Comment: in this case set the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and it will work instantaniously without having to tab out of the control